# Tag an API in Azure API Management with Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to IaC my API Gateway using Terraform. I did all configurations normally, such as backend, products and policies. But reading the documentation, I didn't find any way to set a Tag to API, only create a new one.

[image: Screenshot API management API]

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "test" {
  name                  = "test*******"
  display_name          = "Test*******"
  api_management_name   = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_api_management.example.resource_group_name
  revision              = "1"
  protocols             = ["https"]
  subscription_required = true
  path                  = "test****"

  subscription_key_parameter_names {
    header = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"
    query  = "subscription-key"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Does Terraform support this feature? Is it better to use ARM templates or Powershell in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

As per the [azurerm_api_management_api | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api) document, there is no option to set a tag  to an API in Azure API Management using Terraform.

We can create an API tag for Azure API Management using terraform using below code :

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_tag" "example" {
  api_management_id = "resource id of azure-api-management"
  name              = "tag-name"
}
```

[image]

Now, we can use this powershell command to set the above tag for an API in Azure API Management :

```
New-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "Resource-Group-Name" -ResourceType Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/tags -ResourceName "api-management-name/api-name/tag-name" -Force
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We were missing this feature as well.

Luckily, it got added to the azurerm Terraform provider in [version 0.92.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v2.92.0/CHANGELOG.md) recently: [azurerm_api_management_api_tag](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_tag)

You can use the new resource to assign an existing tag to an API:

```hcl
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "example-api"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_tag" "example" {
  api_management_id = data.azurerm_api_management.example.id
  name              = "example-tag"
  display_name      = "Example Tag"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_tag" "example" {
  api_id = azurerm_api_management_api.example.id
  name   = "example-tag"
}
```